# Wordpress Parent theme vs Child theme updates

Tags: php, wordpress

A former developer I worked with on the past made customizations on child theme, but some of the code was placed on functions.php parent theme, he then placed all his code back on child theme, now a recent parent theme update destroyed all modifications from parent theme functions.php file.

he says it not possible to overwrite his customizations on child theme alone, since they are beyond styles. I read on wordpress documentation that when extensive customizations – beyond styles and a few theme files are made, it is a better option than a child theme to create a parent theme in order to avoid the kind of issues I am facing.

My question:

a. is it possible in your experience that a child theme cannot overwrite certain functionalities from parent theme and if that is the case, there is nothing to do about that ?

b. as an alternative one could write code on parent theme and risk losing it all when update comes around.

c. it´s always possible to overwrite any functionality using child theme no matter how extensive customizations are.

I would appreciate your insights,
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions ...

**Is it possible that a child theme cannot overwrite certain functionalities from a parent theme?**

This depends on how good the parent theme was coded. Basically it is possible that a child theme cannot overwrite functionality from a parent theme. Best practice in that case is, to unregister the parent functionality from the parent theme in your child theme and than register the modified functionality again on the same hook in your child theme.

**As an alternative one could write code on parent theme and risk losing it all when update comes around?**
Don 't do that. Sure, it is possible, that you modify the parent theme. This results into two major problems. Every update can potentially overwrite your changes depending on what files are changed with the update. If you don 't update your parent theme to avoid overriding your changes, your theme becomes insecure and it is possible, that it won 't work with future updates of the wordpress software. So please, do not work in a parent theme code base. Always use a child theme.

**Is it always possible to overwrite any functionality using child theme no matter how extensive customizations are.**

As in your first question it depends on the code quality of your parent theme. The WordPress Codex strongly recommends using function like `function_exists` and `class_exists` in parent themes, so that you can modify the most things. But that is not always the case. Most functions of a parent theme are hooked into action hooks of the WordPress software. You can use these hooks to unregister functions from a parent theme and register your own modified functions in your child theme. The answer to this question is: No, it is not always possible to overwrite functionality of a parent theme. But in most cases it is. Depends on the quality of your parent theme.

Answer (score 1):

You are right whenever possible child theme and custom plugin are the choices to extend parent theme and existing functionalities. Theme and plugin files should have never touched to prevent the situation of yours right now. If you are talking about pure style, [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) should be always able to override the parent theme in almost every aspect. This is the reason why child theme exists. On the other hand, we do not override functionality per se, instead, WordPress developers use hooks to add or modify existing functionalities of both theme and plugin. With that being said,  it is required a hook to be available in order to 'override' a certain functionality. Therefore, it is possible that the original author of plugin or theme didn't provide such hook for extensibility.